# CodeIgniter 3 not working on LAMP

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, virtualhost, codeigniter-3

I have CodeIgniter 3 running locally on MAMP just fine. But, when I pull from my repo and try to set it up on an ec2 instance with LAMP installed, I get a 404. CodeIgniter is in the `/var/www/html` folder

My `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file contains the following:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

mod_rewrite is enabled. The file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    AccessFileName .htaccess
    ServerAdmin admin@yourdomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

    <Directory />
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The file `/var/www/html/application/config/config.php` has the following settings:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['base_url'] = 'http://baseurl.com';
```

My `.htaccess` file is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Set Server name in vhost file. You forgot slash at the end of base url. Does it work with index.php in url?

Comment: Controller (and model) files names beginning with uppercase?

Answer (score 0):

first you check the server configuration. you can use apache error log to find server related issue.
then check error log of application.
 In database.php  check the

```
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
```

because newest Lamp not supported

```
    'dbdriver' => 'mysql',
```